# Is it possible to create a buy button in an external html website which generates a checkout for WordPress WooCommerce?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I have two websites, the main domain, and a subdomain, i want to add a buy button in the HTML main website which generates a checkout page on my subdomain that is installed with Woocommerce and WordPress so people can Checkout, is this possible? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add a button with the add to cart url see below:

Add to cart product with Id 25 and quantity 1.

```
<a href=”https://subdomain.yourdomain.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=25&quantity=1“>Buy Now</a>
```